# не работает composer

Tags: php, composer

На Open Server внезапно перестал работать Composer, не могу установить пакет, не могу обновить существующие пакеты, даже не могу заново установить Composer.

Хочу установить Composer, выбивает:

```
The "https://getcomposer.org/versions" file could not be downloaded: failed to 
open stream: Попытка установить соединение была безуспешной, т.к. от другого 
компьютера за требуемое время не получен нужный отклик, или было разорвано уже 
установленное соединение из-за неверного отклика уже подключенного компьютера.
```

Хочу выполнить команду, выбивает:

```
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
The "https://packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded: failed to 
open stream: Попытка установить соединение была безуспешной, т.к. от другого 
компьютера за требуемое время не получен нужный отклик, или было разорвано уже 
установленное соединение из-за неверного отклика уже подключенного компьютера.
```

- Все ссылки открываются нормально
- Использовал `http` и `https` - без разницы
- `wget http://packagist.org/packages.json` отрабатывает хорошо

Видел подобные проблемы появляются из-за присутствия прокси, но у меня его нет.

---

Вывод `composer diagnose`:

```
Checking platform settings: OK
Checking git settings: OK
Checking http connectivity to packagist: WARNING
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException] 
The "http://packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded: failed to 
open stream: Попытка установить соединение была безуспешной, т.к. от другого 
компьютера за требуемое время не получен нужный отклик, или было разорвано уже 
установленное соединение из-за неверного отклика уже подключенного компьютера.

Checking https connectivity to packagist: WARNING
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException] 
The "http://packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded: failed to 
open stream: Попытка установить соединение была безуспешной, т.к. от другого 
компьютера за требуемое время не получен нужный отклик, или было разорвано уже 
установленное соединение из-за неверного отклика уже подключенного компьютера.  

Checking github.com rate limit: FAIL
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException] 
The "https://api.github.com/rate_limit" file could not be downloaded: failed to 
open stream: Попытка установить соединение была безуспешной, т.к. от другого 
компьютера за требуемое время не получен нужный отклик, или было разорвано уже 
установленное соединение из-за неверного отклика уже подключенного компьютера.

Checking disk free space: OK
Checking pubkeys:
Tags Public Key Fingerprint: 57815BA2 7E54DC31 7ECC7CC5 573090D0  87719BA6 8F3BB723 4E5D42D0 84A14642
Dev Public Key Fingerprint: 4AC45767 E5EC2265 2F0C1167 CBBB8A2B  0C708369 153E328C AD90147D AFE50952
OK
Checking composer version:

[Composer\Downloader\TransportException] 
The "https://getcomposer.org/versions" file could not be downloaded: failed to 
open stream: Попытка установить соединение была безуспешной, т.к. от другого 
компьютера за требуемое время не получен нужный отклик, или было разорвано уже 
установленное соединение из-за неверного отклика уже подключенного компьютера.
```

---

При установке через консоль:

```
php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
```

Тоже выводит ошибку:

```
Warning: copy(https://getcomposer.org/installer): failed to open stream:     , ..          ,       -     .
in Command line code on line 1

Call Stack:
    0.0002     342080   1. {main}() Command line code:0
    0.0002     342080   2. copy() Command line code:1

Dump $_SERVER
   $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] is undefined
   $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] is undefined
Dump $_SESSION
   $_SESSION['*'] is undefined
Dump $_REQUEST
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83636/discussion-on-question-by-human---composer).

Comment: А просто открыть http://packagist.org/packages.json в браузере можете? Видимо, что-то между вами и запрашиваемыми ресурсами не дает до них достучатся.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov Да, все нормально открывается. У вас есть идеи в чем может быть причина?

Comment: Либо что-то с HTTPS протоколом (попробуйте без него), либо прокси.

Comment: Попробуйте в консоли использовать не copy(...) а file_put_contents(file_get_contents('https://getcomposer.org/installer'), 'composer-setup.php');

Comment: @DanielProtopopov С `http` к сожалению та же история.

Comment: @Vladimir Тоже выдает ошибку:(

Comment: Извиняюсь, поменяйте их местами, сперва имя файла, потом содержимое: file_put_contents('composer-setup.php', file_get_contents('https : / / getcomposer.org/installer') );

Comment: @Vladimir Теперь отобразилась ошибка, как при `copy`;)

Comment: Не может ли быть дело в `allow_url_fopen`?

Comment: Проверьте командой в консоли: php -i | grep fopen

Comment: @Vladimir Все хорошо:( Уже совсем не понимаю в чем может быть проблема.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможно всё падает из-за timeout-та. Попробуйте увеличить эти значения в **php.ini**

```
[PHP]

max_input_time = 3600

default_socket_timeout = 3600

max_execution_time = 3600

upload_max_filesize = 10M
```

Comment: Да, вы абсолютно правы, проблема оказалась в `default_socket_timeout`. Спасибо большое.

Comment: @Human рад что помогло, а где вознаграждение за конкурс, вроде я первым дал ответ :)

Comment: К сожалению не мог понять кто первый догадался. Комментарий под вторым ответом или ваш ответ. Поэтому разделил балы. Заранее прошу прощения.

Comment: @Human да всё нормально, главное вам помогло :)

Answer (score 2):

UPD: при внимательном изучении текста варнинга до меня дошло

Композер использует функции для работы с файлами для http-запроов, это возможно только при включенной директиве `allow_url_fopen`. Кроме того, опции контекста http (такие как таймаут, например) не задаются явно и используются значения по умолчанию. Для таймаута значением по умолчанию будет значение `default_socket_timeout`. Если `default_socket_timeout` выставлен в 0, то скачать файл из интернета скорее всего не получится :-)

Измените значение `default_socket_timeout` на что-то более адекватное (например 60).

Comment: Теперь совсем не в понятках;) Все хорошо отработало.

Comment: @Human вы проверили состояние директивы `allow_url_fopen` (это в php.ini обычно задаётся)? http://php.net/manual/ru/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen

Comment: Та да, включен;(

Comment: @Human а `default_socket_timeout` какой?

Comment: `0` стоит. Недавно сокет настраивал

Comment: @Human это ответ на ваш вопрос :-)

Comment: Мой мир перевернулся;) Проблема реально оказалась в `default_socket_timeout`

Comment: Спасибо большое. Не знаю кто из вас первый догадался. Мне показалось что @FarkhodDaniyarov, поэтому ему присвоил ответ, а вам очки;)

Answer (score 0):

Это проблема новой версии, для корректной работы советую использовать встроенную консоль в ней все работает корректно [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: К огромному сожалению не помогло..

Answer (score 0):

Через консоль ОС перейдите в папку проекта и после

```
php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
php composer-setup.php
php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"
```

php composer-setup.php --filename=composer

пока не появятся главное phar

```
composer.phar
composer.json 
composer.lock
```

Если нету то от руки закиньте его https://getcomposer.org/download/ последнию версию

после уже чекайте `composer -v`

Php версию проверьте все на совместимость и главное директорию

Comment: Благодарю за участие, но я в вопросе написал что через консоль тоже не устанавливается и выдает ошибку. А вручную то можно положить файлы, но это не решит суть проблемы.